# Choosing to accept between an answer that helped me the most and a more popular answer

Tags: support, accepting

There were several good answers in my recent question in main: [Should I place \title, \author, \date in the preamble or after \begin{document}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/92702/should-i-place-title-author-date-in-the-preamble-or-after-begindocument). I am leaning towards accepting *the answer that helped me the most* or which I think is the most practical one at the moment. I don't know if that can be taken as going against the consensus (although at this point the differences in upvotes are not that great).

Comment: It's your tick I think you should give it to the answer you found most helpful or used. (I'd say you should give it to me, but I didn't answer that one:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your comment was insightful. You could have turned that into an answer:-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Definitely go for the one that was the most helpful to you. The [faq](https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) say:

> When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark
>   it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the
>   left of the answer.
>
> [accept an answer http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png)
>
> This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to
>   your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people
>   that you’re getting value from the community. (And if you *don’t* do
>   this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers
>   for more of your questions!)

Comment: You can also upvote multiple answers to your question, thus rewarding good ones even when you have accepted another.